# Having trouble with C program output

Tags: c, compiler-errors, output, borland-c

As far as I know regardless of any other issues the program below should print out the title and menu options, and then prompt for user input.

However, it does absolutely nothing and when I stop the execution it prints out the menu etc and then, as it hasn't asked for the user inputted option it repeatedly prints the "This is not a valid option" line.

*EDIT: I have completely removed the loops. All I have in the program is print the title, print the menu, ask for user input, and I still get nothing to the console until after I terminate. Is there something wrong with my asking for input?

*EDIT2*: It's definitely the scanf as without it everything works. I ran the code with an added function to print out the value stored in option and it told me -1 when I hadn't previously set it to 0 before asking the user to input. The program seems to be automatically assigning option instead of bothering to ask the user what they want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    /*Print Title*/
    printf("Maths Quiz Game \n"); 
    printf("\n");

    int i;
    int rightCount = 0; //count of right answers
    int wrongCount = 0; //count of wrong answers
    int questions = 0; //user input for number of questions
    int exit = 0; //store exit option
    int option = 0; //menu option

    while(exit == 0) //while loop that keeps program running until exit is chosen
    {
        /*Menu Options*/
        printf("Please choose an option from the menu below. Enter the number of your choice. \n");
        printf(" 1. Choose number of questions for this round. (Max = 5) \n");
        printf(" 2. Start Quiz \n");
        printf(" 3. Display total of right and wrong answers. (Only availanle after quiz) \n");
        printf(" 4. Exit Game \n");

        scanf("%d", &option); //taking user menu option

        /*Error check for any input that is not a valid option. It continues until valid entry*/
        while((option != 1) || (option != 2) || (option != 3) || (option != 4))
        {
            printf("\n That is not a valid option. Please try again. \n");
            scanf("%d", &option);
        }
```

Comment: Your code is not complete I guess

Comment: `while((option != 1) || (option != 2) || (option != 3) || (option != 4))`  -->> `while(option != 1 && option != 2 && option != 3 && option != 4)`  Or: `while(option < 1  || option > 4)`

Comment: Hi, the code hasn't even been started yet. I was just at the stage where I had put in the invalid entry checker and said I'd give it a go. The rest of the code at the minute is just if(option=??) then print the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the printf function in that it didn’t print out until after you had entered the following options, it didn’t ask until after the user had answered. A simple flush after the printf sorted this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
while((option != 1) || (option != 2) || (option != 3) || (option != 4))
```

what ever option value you enters assume 1, 1st condition of while() will be false but remaining are true so enters into loop and prints "That is not a valid option. Please try again." so **replace || with logical And(&&)**.

```
while((option != 1) && (option != 2) && (option != 3) && (option != 4))
```

now here if you entered correct input it will not display "That is not a valid option. Please try again"

Comment: While I see your point and I have changed the code, that is not the main issue here. I'm not getting any output at all. When I run the code, nothing shows on the screen at all. When I finally get sick of waiting and click stop executing, the termination screen pops up with all the output it should have given me when I ran, including multiple Not a valid option line.  even after changing from or to and like you said

Comment: provide the code after while(cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && cond4), then only I can say anything. because if you enters options b/w 1 to 4, it will not print anything and it shouldn't.

Comment: if(option == 1){ printf("\n Option 1\n"); }    and then the same for 2-4.   I'm not sure I understand what you're saying though

Answer (score 1):

How about changing

```
while((option != 1) || (option != 2) || (option != 3) || (option != 4))
{
    printf("\n That is not a valid option. Please try again. \n");
    scanf("%d", &option);
}
```

to something else like

```
if ((option != 1) || (option != 2) || (option != 3) || (option != 4))
{
    printf("\n That is not a valid option. Please try again. \n");
    // scanf("%d", &option);  // This is probably not required
}
```

or

```
if ( option >= 1 && option <= 4)
{
    printf("\n That is not a valid option. Please try again. \n");
    // scanf("%d", &option);
}
```

Because you are using infinite loop outside, why would you need one inside? All you need is to check the option and show the menu if an unavailable option is selected.

All of your logic you can put in this `if` afterward, one for each option selected.

---

Better use `switch` for good understanding

```
/* After selecting an option */
switch (option)
{
    case 1:
         /* Do the operation according */
         break;

    case 2:
         /* Do the operation according */
         break;

    case 3:
         /* Do the operation according */
         break;

    case 4:
         /* Do the operation according */
         break;

    default:
         /* If none of the option selected */
         printf ("Wrong input! \n")
         break;
}
```

Hope you got it.

Comment: Feel free to put a comment if anything else you wanted? @Amanda6276

Comment: Hi, that was a really good suggestion and you've changed the output I get when I terminate the code. However, I'm still not getting anything to my output at all. If I remove the while loop completely I get the Maths Quiz line then nothing but once the loop goes in, nothing. I stare at an empty screen until i terminate, then it shows the title and menu on a loop. Do I have an issue that would cause this?

Comment: It's not printing the title line that comes before the while loop though. And I have changed the inner loop to be an if statement instead. Should the program not ask for user input as I put in under the menu options before continuing to run the while loop?

Comment: That actually depends on the requirement of your programme. If you want to be the menu only once, you can do that by putting it outside. But as if you want to continue after completing one operation for the selected option, that should be inside. All statements inside the loop will be repeated only.

Comment: I don't know if you've seen my edit above but I was trying to figure it out on my own and I removed the whole while loop, basically making my program a print out the menu and ask for user input. It still doesn't print anything though. Do you think my input request is wrong or is there anything else it could be? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Input request after the menu is fine. You see, before getting hands-on code first you should decide what you exactly want to do by drawing all on a paper, how the flow of your programme should be, when to ask for input and when to do an operation. Once you got the logic and algorithm, the code will be not a big deal.

Comment: I removed the input request, ran the code and everything printed out fine. I know that its the right format and in the right spot but for some reason its not letting  me do anything if its there.

Comment: Don't worry. You will figure it out.